# Python regex not printing contents in new list

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regex to extract some patterns in a string.

```
import re
a=[]
maxline="i have a Prof.John and As Maria a bike"
for line in maxline:
   res = re.findall(r'(?:Prof[.](\w+))', line)
   if res: 
      a.extend(res)
   res = re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))', line)
   if res:
      a.extend(res)
   res = re.findall(r'\w+(?==\w)', line)
   if res:
      a.extend(res)
   print res
```

Expected Output:

```
John
Maria
```

Instead i get output as :

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over *individual characters*, not over lines:

```
>>> maxline="i have a Prof.John and As Maria a bike"
>>> for line in maxline:
...     print line
... 
i

h
a
v
e
# .... etc.
```

These individual characters don't match your expressions.

Change `maxline` to be a list; perhaps by splitting it on newlines with [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for line in maxline.splitlines():
```

and printing out `a`, *not* `res`:

```
    print a
```

Comment: and a quick fix is to put the string into a list, e.g.  maxline=["i have a Prof.John and As Maria a bike"]

Answer (score 1):

Simply you could do like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> maxline="i have a Prof.John and As Maria a bike"
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=Prof\.)\w+|(?<=As )\w+', maxline)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
John
Maria
```

Updated the answer to include the third pattern,

```
>>> maxline="i have a Prof.John and As Maria a bike=f"
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=Prof\.)\w+|(?<=As )\w+|\w+(?==\w)', maxline)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
John
Maria
bike
```